# Rails 4: Odd Activerecord sort order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

Like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11993683/rails-3-2-activerecord-association-order-with-eager-loading-and-ordering) I am looking to eager load another object and then sort the list based on a value from the eager loaded object.

Given parent `Foo` and child `Bar`:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bar, foreign_key: :foo_name, primary_key: :name   
  has_one  :most_recent_bar, -> { order created at desc }, foreign_key: :foo_name, primary_key: :name   
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo, foreign_key: :foo_name, primary_key: :name   
end
```

I am looking to show a list of `Foo`s, and then sort them by `Bar.value` and `Foo.name`. I am only looking for the most recently created `Bar`, so it's sorted in reverse order and limited to 1. So:

```
@foos = Foo.includes(:most_recent_bar).order('bar.value asc, foo.name asc')
```

**The problem:** The order statement above is changing `most_recent_bar`. It is ordering all `Foo.bars` and then picking the most recent of the sorted list. It is only then ordering the list by `Foo.name`.

**The Question:** How can I appropriately order these eager loaded values such that `most_recent_bar` is legitimately the most recently created, and then order the list of `Foo`s based on `most_recent_bar.value`?

**Edit for SQL from my live code:**

```
    Foo.includes(:most_recent_bar).order('bars.value asc, name asc')
  SQL (7.9ms)  SELECT "foos"."id" AS t0_r0, "foos"."name" AS t0_r1, "foos"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "foos"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "bars"."id" AS t1_r0, "bars"."content" AS t1_r1, "bars"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "bars"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "bars"."foo_name" AS t1_r4, "bars"."version" AS t1_r5, "bars"."bbj_status" AS t1_r6, "bars"."host" AS t1_r7, "bars"."value" AS t1_r8 FROM "foos" LEFT OUTER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."foo_name" = "foos"."name" ORDER BY bars.value asc, name asc
```

**Edit for broken SQL after fix** Seems to be looking for two created ats, and I'm not sure where the ambiguous one is coming from!

```
My error SQL Foo.includes(:most_recent_foo).merge(bar.most_recent).order('bars.repo asc')
  SQL (0.6ms)  SELECT "foos"."id" AS t0_r0, "foos"."name" AS t0_r1, "foos"."created_at" AS t0_r2, "foos"."updated_at" AS t0_r3, "bars"."id" AS t1_r0, "bars"."content" AS t1_r1, "bars"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "bars"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "bars"."foo_name" AS t1_r4, "bars"."version" AS t1_r5, "bars"."bbj_status" AS t1_r6, "bars"."host" AS t1_r7, "bars"."repo" AS t1_r8 FROM "foos" LEFT OUTER JOIN "bars" ON "bars"."foo_name" = "foos"."name" ORDER BY created_at DESC, bars.created_at desc, bars.repo asc
PG::Error: ERROR:  column reference "created_at" is ambiguous
LINE 1: …bars”.”foo_name" = "foos"."name"  ORDER BY created_at...
```

Comment: Can you add the SQL output for this query?

Comment: I just did a quick search and replace, should be good to go with the SSCE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I finally understand the question (I hope), here's the bad news:  SQL doesn't have any simple commands for sorting in the manner you require - ORDER BY alone isn't going to suffice.  Because of this, ActiveRecord doesn't either provide a simple solution (ActiveRecord is simply an ORM with a good/very good SQL statement generator).  What you require is quite complex for any ORM to do efficiently.

The good news is that you *can* do this with a complete understanding how you can use SQL to accomplish this, and a bit of work to inform AR what you are trying to do.  First, the SQL.

There are various approaches to sort by a MAX of a collection of associated rows, and the most efficient will vary by DBMS and the actual data. Because you are using PostgreSQL, you might want to use a window function to accomplish this.  The problem is that using a window function to work cleanly with eager loading is going to be extremely difficult.  So what other options are there using vanilla SQL?  One simple approach involves using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT /* some-eager-loaded-fields */
FROM foos
LEFT JOIN bars ON foos.id = bars.foo_id
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM bars b2
    WHERE b2.foo_id = bars.foo_id AND b2.created_at > bars.created_at
  )
ORDER BY bars.value, foos.name
```

The NOT EXISTS will exclude any bars where a greater `created_at` exists for that `foo_id`.  This leaves you with the only bar that has no greater `created_at` - the MAX.  Now that we have the query, how would we generate that in AR?

The subquery would look like this (using Arel to help format the alias correctly):

```
b2 = Bar.arel_table.alias('b2')
Bar.select('1').from(b2).where('b2.foo_id = bars.foo_id AND b2.created_at > bars.created_at')
```

This can now be used to determine most recent:

```
def Bar < AR::Base
  def self.most_recent
    b2 = arel_table.alias('b2')
    where Bar.select('1').from(b2).
      where('b2.foo_id = bars.foo_id AND b2.created_at > bars.created_at').
      exists.not
  end
end
```

And your `most_recent_bar` association:

```
def Foo < AR::Base
  has_many :bars
  has_one :most_recent_bar, ->{ merge(Bar.most_recent) }, class_name: 'Bar'
end
```

Now your query should just work:

```
Foo.includes(:most_recent_bar).order('bars.value asc, foos.name asc')
```

Comment: Before refactoring, it seemed to be working but it was listing a lot more than just one most_recent_bar. Now I can't get it to work at all. Will continue messing with this. Just out of curiosity (saw something like this yesterday actually) why most_recent_foo? I'll look into Bill Karwin's recommendation. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, mixed that up with `most_recent_bar`. Fixed.

Comment: @user1870954 - Change the `most_recent` class method implementation to specify the table name: `order('bars.created_at desc')`.

Comment: I lied, this doesn't actually do what I need it to do. It's ordering the main list by the time the Bar was created. Pwomp!

Comment: @user1870954 - I'm confused, isn't that the sort order you wanted? "order the list of Foos based on most_recent_bar.value". Please clarify how the main list should be sorted.

Comment: Ok, I think I see the miscommunication.  You want the most_recent_bar to be joined and using just that set of bars _as a basis_, sort on bars.value and then foos.name.  In addition to the sorting, the most_recent_bar should also be eager loaded.  Is that it?

Comment: Yup! Eager load the most recent Bar for easy access, and then sort the list of Foo's based off of Bar.some_value and Foo.some_value.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL, PostgreSQL?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL on all environments.